# Graph API: Upload contents of driveItem throws 501 not_implemented error for AzureChina

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-china

I want to update the content of the file on OneDrive item. For that I used this API.

> PUT /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

This works perfectly fine for non China azure with Microsoft graph endpoint.

> https://graph.microsoft.com

However, when I am trying this on AzureChina it is throwing me 501 error.

> https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn

Error:

This is the error response I am getting event though I am uploading data to file.

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "notSupported",
        "message": "Cannot upload content to an item representing a folder.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-05-10T09:01:12",
            "request-id": "98a8b075-bb90-42fe-8620-7303e669f4ec",
            "client-request-id": "98a8b075-bb90-42fe-8620-7303e669f4ec"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this not implemented in AzureChina?
Another thing is graph explorer does not work with AzureChina. Is there separate graph explorer available for AzureChina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Azure China, Work around for Graph API is to use SharePoint REST API v1.

To upload the file contents of drive items

```
URL: https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='newFile.txt',overwrite=true)
Headers:
"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
Method: "POST",
Body:
<File_contents>
```

Auth URL: [https://login.partner.microsoftonline.cn/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.partner.microsoftonline.cn/%7B%7BTenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)

Access Token URL: [https://login.partner.microsoftonline.cn/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.partner.microsoftonline.cn/%7B%7BTenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Scope : https://{tenantId}-my.sharepoint.cn/.default

Make sure you have added appropriate API Permissions for SharePoint & granted Admin consent in Azure AD portal within corresponding Application.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments#supported-features) OneDrive and Excel features of Graph API are limited by Microsoft Cloud China but without more details what exactly is not supported.

Comment: For me get items API is working for AzureChina. But not content API. I did found the Graph Explorer for AzureChina but looks like it is still in development.